# How do I do a conditional replace in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Powershell Newbie looking for some help.

I've got a powershell script which changes a priority value inside a text file to have a value of 50:

```
if ($line.contains("Priority") ) 
{
   $LastComma = $line.LastIndexOf(",") +1
   $N = $line.Substring(0,$LastComma)
   $N = $N + "50"
   $lines[$counter] = $N

}
```

This works fine and does exactly what I want it to, but I now need to modify it so it changes the priority value to 45 if there is also the following line present:

`Provider = XYZ`

If this Provider value is not XYZ then all Priority values are set to 50 as before. Anyone have any advice on how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This example illustrates using Powershell with several concepts:

1. Matching each line using regular expressions
2. Replacing each line using regular expressions
3. Using a `switch` statement

Here's a test file:

```
Set-Content test.txt "Provider=ABC,Priority=3                                                            
Provider=DEF,Priority=4
Not a provider                                                                                                                        
Provider=XYZ,Priority=5"
```

You can transform the test file line by line using the 
`switch` statement (thanks @TheIncorrigible1)

```
switch -Regex -File test.txt
{                                                                                                                                        
   'Provider=XYZ.+Priority='
   {
       $_ -replace "Priority=\d+","Priority=45"
       continue
   }                                                                                                                                    

   'Priority='                                                                                                                          
   {                                                                                                                                    
       $_ -replace "Priority=\d+","Priority=50"
       continue
   }                                                                                                                                    

   default                                                                                                                              
   {                                                                                                                                    
       $_
       continue
   }                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: `switch` has a `-File` parameter.  No need to slow everything down by using `Get-Content -> ForEach-Object`.  Additionally, you want to use `continue` instead of `break` or it will stop the processing of the switch (although reaching a non-default condition is an implicit break)

Answer (score 0):

Please make the effort to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.

Without any more information than what was provided, here is a draft of a solution:

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
  $value = "XYZ"
  $check = $false
  if ($line.contains("Provider = $value")) {
    $check = $true
  }
  if ($line.contains("Priority")) {
    if ($check) {
      $priority = 45
    } else {
      $priority = 50
    }
    $LastComma = $line.LastIndexOf(",") +1
    $N = $line.Substring(0,$LastComma)
    $N = $N + "$priority"
    $lines[$counter] = $N
  }
}
```

**Remark:** This assume that the `Provider` tag will be found prior to the `Priority` tags.